# How to pass value to constructor of a class in another assembly

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I'm using a service in an assembly with following definition:

```
 internal class BinanceService : IBinanceService
    {
        private readonly IBinanceClient _binanceClient;

        public BinanceService(IBinanceClient binanceClient)
        {
            _binanceClient = binanceClient;
            _binanceClient.SetApiCredentials("u4TX2adUAkpCyRDrStohFNf5otSlw7S7W077X9BQ7KGQbC7C2Y", "uxadyxYyMRPF3caQM0pbzT5naEA9BntqFREJRNIQIBxHNyS");
        }
}
```

the above code lives in an assembly (let's call it A) which has been referenced in assembly B. Now I want to pass different parameters for SetApiCredentials("","") while calling the IBinanceService from assembly B. How can I do that??
thanks

Comment: Looks like the method is static.  It is probably in a different namespace so you are mising the namespace.  So if namespace is Application2 you use : Application2._binanceClient.SetApiCredentials("u4TX2adUAkpCyRDrStohFNf5otSlw7S7W077X9BQ7KGQbC7C2Y", "uxadyxYyMRPF3caQM0pbzT5naEA9BntqFREJRNIQIBxHNyS");

Comment: Can you change code in both assemblies?

Comment: Depending on where you actually *create* the instance of `BinanceService` you need to be able to access that class by making it public.

Comment: Is this for dependency injection?

Answer (score 2):

Your class is internal, that means that from inside the assembly, you can create it normally via the constructor. Put the credentials also in the constructor and you can chose them arbitrary:

```
internal class BinanceService : IBinanceService
    {
        private readonly IBinanceClient _binanceClient;

        public BinanceService(IBinanceClient binanceClient, string credentials)
        {
            _binanceClient = binanceClient;
            _binanceClient.SetApiCredentials(credentials);
        }
}
```

From outside, you won't be able to access the class. Create a factory which returns an instance of `IBinanceService` (I assume that the interface is public). The caller should not be able to pass its own credentials string. Hence when you call this method, you only the credentials stored in the constant `externalCredentials` will be used.

```
public static class BinanceServiceFactory()
{
    private const string externalCredentials = "something";

    public static IBinanceService Create(IBinanceClient client)
    {
       return new BinanceService(client, externalCredentials);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the best solution for this is the factory.  in your solution how should I use BinanceServiceFactory as I'm using constructor injection while using IBinanceService  in another assembly?

Comment: The problem is, only the second assembly has access to credential variables and they should be feed from the caller assembly(assembly B).

Comment: @Ehsan: In that case, add it also as a parameter to the factory. If you call it from assembly B, you can give the credentials. I thought that you want to enforce different credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but if this is about dependency injection this is a pattern I've used:

```
public class XCredentialsProvider
{
public string ClientId {get;set;}
public string Secret {get;set;

// Constructor here
}

(...)

public BinanceService(IBinanceClient binanceClient, XCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider)
{
   _binanceClient = binanceClient;
   _binanceClient.SetApiCredentials(credentialsProvider.ClientId, credentialsProvider.Secret);
}
```

Then in Unity config:

```
container.RegisterInstance(new XCredentialsProvider(clientId: ..., secret: ...));
```

---

Another option is to not to call SetApiCredentials and just accept client that is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class is marked as internal it is not exposed to referencing assembly. You either need to make it public or if that can't be possible, make it a friend assembly.

See this: [Friend Assembly in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend)